# Map example in java

Tags: java

I would like to write lastnamesByFirstname method.
In the people lists, there are bunch of people, and each person have two field the firstname and the second name. I would like to write a method which will turn back in the following way, key value would be the firstname, and the value list would be those name which firstnames are the same. I tried with groupingby wiht sorting buts somehow never worked.

```
* {
     *  "Mary" -> ["Smith", "Silver"]
     *  "Joe" -> ["Smith"]
     * }
     */
    static Map<String, List<String>> lastnamesByFirstname(List<Person> people){
        
}
```

my attempt look like this, but the type would be not matching with the return type.

```
var peopleStream= people.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Person::getFirstName));
```

Comment: *"I tried with groupingby wiht sorting buts somehow never worked."* please [edit] your question to include your attempts (especially the group-by one) so we can work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second parameter of `groupingBy`, you can transform `List<Person>` to `List<String>` using `mapping`:

```java
var peopleStream = people.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Person::getFirstName,
                mapping(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it easily with a lambda function.

```
static Map<String, List<String>> lastnamesByFirstname(List<Person> people){
        people.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, // Get first name as key of the map
                  Collectors.mapping(
                      Person::getLastName, //Get lastName as value of the list
                      Collectors.toList()))); //Specify that you want to collect as a list.
}
```